# Remove CALayers after animation stop one by one

Tags: stack, calayer

I want to make a stack of coin, when user click "Fly in" -> coin'll fly in a curved path and arrange in a stack. I used CALayer:

```
CALayers *coinLayer = [CALayers layer];
coinLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
coinLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"head coin.png"].CGImage;
coinLayer.frame = CGRectMake(100, 500 - (10*coin), 55, 21);
coin = coin + 1;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:coinLayer];
```

I've done with animation in curved path but if i add my coinLayer in this way, then how can i remove CALayer if i don't add it in an array.

For example, i have a stack of number, i add 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in the stack. When remove 4 numbers, it will do from 9 down to 8... down to 6 one by one. In my code, is that correct when i add CALayer in view's layer? How can i remove layers one by one as same as example?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can anyone help me? I used "removeFromSuperLayer", but i just remove one layer that i've just added. But it didn't worked with the layer before. If i used method "insertSublayers: atIndex:", layers can be added into view's layers. But i can not find method that can remove layer at index. If anyone have solved the same problem, help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating and deleting CALayer objects it's better to store them in an array and simply set their hidden property whenever you need them.

in the header:

```
    NSMutableArray* coins;
```

In the m file:

```
-(void)newCoin;
{
    //create the array if it doesn't already exist - could add this to your init
    if(!coins)
    {
        coins = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    for(CALayer* aCoin in coins)
    {
        //find the first hidden coin and use it
        if(aCoin.hidden)
        {
            //reset the coins position to where you want the "new" coin
            return;
        }
    }
    //didn't find any unused coins - make a new one
    [coins addObject:[self createCoin]];
```

When the animation finishes simply set the coin's hidden property to be true.

```
coin.hidden = YES;
```

I use this method to handle thousands of CALayer objects at once and it's much more resource friendly than constantly creating new CALayers.